# Find a right triangle section of a larger one

Tags: trigonometry

I'm programming a game, and find myself stumped.  I know the target ball (dx, dy) and (cue x, cue y) and the x value of the camera.  It's been 20 years and I'm sad to say I've lost some ground here.

So, I need the coordinates at the `^` character, where the diagonal intersects the camera bounds.  Thank you.

```
  //
  //              . dx, dy (ball)
  // off camera  /|      
  // __________ /_|____ camera x
  //           /^ | need these coordinates (limit_x, limit_y)
  //  camera  / | |     
  //         /__| | 
  // cue x,y^     | 
  // _____________|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to say.

Geometrically, you want to find the point where the line between $(x_{cue},y_{cue})$ and $(dx,dy)$ meets the line defined by $x=x_{cam}$ where $x_{cam}$ is the $x$-value of the camera. You already have the $x$-coordinate ($x_{cam}$) so you only need the $y$-coordinate, call it $y_{cam}$.

The slope of the diagonal line is $\left( \frac{dy-y_{cue}}{dx-x_{cue}}\right)$ and we can plug into the equation for a line to find that the $y$-intercept is $y_{cue} - \left( \frac{dy-y_{cue}}{dx-x_{cue}}\right)x_{cue}$. Hence, we find that

$$ y_{cam} = y_{cue} +\left( \frac{dy-y_{cue}}{dx-x_{cue}}\right) (x_{cam} - x_{cue}) $$ so that your point of intersection is
$$ (x_{cam}, y_{cam}) = \left( x_{cam}, y_{cue} +\left( \frac{dy-y_{cue}}{dx-x_{cue}}\right) (x_{cam} - x_{cue})  \right)$$

Comment: I only have the y-coordinate of the upper bound of the camera.  I'll take a closer look to see whether or not I can solve for cam-x.

Comment: Ah, I see. You should be able to rearrange the equation in the middle to get what you need.

Comment: I'm easily confused. Thank you so much for your patience.